# Are percentages relative to the window or the document?

Tags: css, width

In CSS, if I set the width attribute to 100%, like so:

```
width: 100%;
```

If the width of the document is larger than the width of the window (horizontal scrolling), the width of the element is only the width of the window. If I scroll to the right, it gets cut off immediately.

How can I use CSS to set the width of the element to have a `min-width` of the document width so it doesn't get cut off when scrolling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percentage based width is dependent on the width of the parent element. So if you set width 50%, it will be 50% of the parent container. Therefore you need to ensure that all the parent elements are properly sized.

There may be a solution using absolutely positioned elements. However this depends on the position attributes of the parents as well.

There is no construct to get the "document width" on a page (in pure css). You are constrained by parent elements in nearly any case.

However a solution may be achieved with Javascript.

I would suggest you investigate the size of the chain of parent elements with Firebug or another browser debugger.

Comment: The only parent element is the <body> tag. Shouldn't it be equivalent to the width of the body, i.e. the document? I have never seen this happen before, but then again, I have never been working with a browser width below 600px.

Comment: Yes. It should. Could you post a screenshot or a jsfiddle of your issue?

Comment: You can just go to my website, www.tapescan.com Make your browser width smaller than 970px and scroll to the right a bit. You will see the gray background behind the big image in the middle is not the full width of the page, no matter what I do to it or its parents.

Comment: With padding on your header your min document size will be 1010px. I would suggest you set the body min-width to 1010px.